# Create a HashSet<T> dynamically?

Tags: c#

I need to create a HashSet dynamically. However, the following code doesn't work?

```
object paramX = 1; // Parameter
var type = paramX.GetType();

var hs = (HashSet<>)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(HashSet<>).MakeGenericType(type)); 
// hs has runtime type of HashSet<int> for paramX of an int value
hs.Add(paramX); // Error
```

`hs` has the runtime type of `HashSet<typeof(type)>` but its compile time type is object so `hs.Add(1)` doens't work.

Comment: `HashSet<T>` doesn't derive from anything called `HashSet` so you're not casting to anything in its type hierarchy. You can do that in Java because, due to type erasure, those are not distinct types, but they *are* distinct types in .NET. `HashSet<T>` doesn't implement non-generic collection interfaces like `IDictionary`. How do you plan on using the object you get?

Comment: Please [edit] the post to clarify your exact problem. The code in the post indeed demonstrates how to "Create a HashSet<T> dynamically". As @madreflection said your question seem to be very different from what is written in the post...

Comment: You cannot use a generic type at compile-type if you know its generic type argument only at runtime. What to do depends on what you intend to do with the instance.

Comment: @IllidanS4wantsMonicaback Of course you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
System.Type type = typeof(int); // parameter

var hs = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(HashSet<>).MakeGenericType(type));
```

To use it...

```
((dynamic)hs).Add(1);
```

---

You may also do this:

```
dynamic hs = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(HashSet<>).MakeGenericType(type));
```

And there's no need to cast to dynamic...

```
hs.Add(1);
```

Comment: Down vote because?

Comment: Upvoted. I will mark it an answer if there is no other way to do it without using dynamic.

Comment: There *are* other ways but good advice requires more information about how you intend to use it. Edit your question to add context.

Comment: @ca9163d9 This is what `dynamic` is intended for. When a type is unknown until runtime. At least you know you need a `HashSet<T>`. I'm sorry your question was closed, I'm not sure how it could be any clearer. Many people lack imagination, something outside of their limited understanding couldn't possibly be right.

Comment: @madreflection Prove it. The question is clear enough.